# execute .BAT file in installshield

Tags: batch-file, installshield, custom-action

I am developing a package and i need to run one `.bat` file that will install a windows service for me.
I need 2 things:

1. steps to make custom action that will run `.bat` files? or other may to run .bat file.
2. how to make this custom action with the installation process(for example: just after license agreement)?

*note: my service that I am installing is Delphi service.
Regards.

Answer (score 4):

Ideally, you should look into creating a component that installs the service using MSI standard action InstallService.

Otherwise, you can use the following steps to execute the batch file during installation.

1. Create a deferred type 50 custom action (EXE file having a path specified by a property value).
2. Set it's source to [SystemFolder]\cmd.exe.
3. Set it's target to "/c path-to-batch-file-on-target-system"
4. Schedule it action near InstallService.

Also, don't forget to add a rollback custom action that reverts whatever modifications the batch file is doing and schedule it right before this custom action.

[Edited Step 3]

Comment: dear,How can i schedule it near InstallService? in InstallExecute Sequence, there is no "Install Service"

Comment: Sorry. I was talking about [InstallServices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369540(v=vs.85).aspx)